# How to tell Vim not to use ~/.vim

Tags: vim, settings

By default Vim is looking for plugins and other stuff in `~/.vim`.

Is there any way to tell Vim to search for plugins, etc. in `~/.other_folder` and force it to ignore `~/.vim` entirely?

Comment: you should check out `:h runtimepath`

Comment: Why not simply symlink that other folder to ~/.vim?

Answer (score 4):

Vim uses the comma-separated paths from `'runtimepath'` to determine where to look for `:runtime`'d files.

You can change that option either in `~/.vimrc` (which is sourced as the very first script), or by passing the `set rtp=...` commands on Vim's command-line via `--cmd` (the commands passed with `-c` are only applied after startup).